# Gradle changing compile spring-boot-starter-web to implementation causes error: package org.springframework.http does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm currently in the process of converting a project from using compile to using implementation with Gradle 5.4.1.

I'm running into an issue where using the following works fine:

`compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'`

Where the following does not:

`implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'`

Using implementation causes the following error to appear:

```
/Path/To/File/AFileName.java error: package org.springframework.http does not exist
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
                               ^
```

I'm specifically specifying release version 2.2.2 in both cases so it should not be fetching a newer version with changes to the class location of HttpStatus.

Does anybody know what might be causing this breaking behaviour?

Comment: How is your code arranged? Do you only have a single module or are you using a multi-module build? If it's a multi-module build is the compilation error occurring in the module where you made the change from `compile` to `implementation` or in another module that depends upon it?

Comment: Hi Andy,
It's a single module project.

Comment: Hmm, that's a strange one in that case. What does `./gradlew dependencies --configuration=compileClasspath` show?